# UE4 Gameplay Ability Systems - Triggered a break point error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint, unreal-gameplay-ability-system

I'm relatively new to using the UE4 Gameplay Ability System. What I'm trying to do is create an ability task for a gameplay ability that's made from blueprint. When I debugged it in VS studio, I get this error when it was trying to instantiate a new ability task. However, I'm not sure what the problem here is. The sample project I downloaded had the exact same setup and it works. I suspect that because the "GA_Ability" name didn't get changed in the VS studio debugging it worked out just fine, but for my project it ended up changing "GA_CombatAbility" to "Default__GA_CombatAbility", adding the "Default__" at the beginning of the prefex, and when VS Studio tried to search for an object with that exact name, it couldn't find any and returned the tiggered breakpoint error. That's my speculation. But as I said I'm relatively new to this so I could be wrong here.

[This is the screenshot. My ability name here is "GA_CombatAbility"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58G2W.png)

[VS Studio Debug Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxKpt.png)

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve my own problem. In one of my gameplay ability, I set its instance policy to NonInstanced, which doesn't allow you to store states or bind to ability tasks. What you need to do is to set the instance policy to InstancePerActor which allows you to fully activate your abilities. The section in the document can be found here.

https://github.com/tranek/GASDocumentation?fbclid=IwAR33fhViZBZQJhbjIBQK4KcKzhDZ289IKwYE1-jzeZ_A6g7ww9khXJht6Vg#concepts-ga-instancing